# How to fix crashes if statement in c

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement

T have N input for array inside `main int()`. After assign the input you need to check is the input of the array static or not. My idea is to make function to get `IsMonoStatic(T)` return boolean and 3 another function. I'll show them below. If the function return true then I must print something in terminal somehow it just working for `IsMonoStatic(T)`, when I try input that return true for `IsMonoNotSmaller(T)` after assigning the input the terminal crashing literally not printing the message and the terminal is just freezing, I need to use `ctrl + c` in order to get out of my executing program.

First condition is working at terminal when IsMonoStatic(T) return true

```
4
1
1
1
1
Array monotonik statik
```

But when i try another input, the program is crash.

Here is my code program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "array.h"
#include "boolean.h"

boolean IsMonoNotSmaller (TabInt T)
{
    // kamus lokal
    IdxType i; boolean cek;
    // algoritma
    i = GetFirstIdx(T);
    cek = true; // masih dalam kondisi cek
    while ((i<GetLastIdx(T))&&(cek==true)){
        if (T.TI[i]<=T.TI[i+1]){
            cek = true; // benar maka cek lagi
            i++;
        } else{
            cek = false; // berhenti loop
        }
    }
    return cek;
}

boolean IsMonoNotGreater (TabInt T)
{
    // kamus lokal
    IdxType i; boolean cek;
    // algoritma
    i = GetFirstIdx(T);
    cek = true;
    while ((i<GetLastIdx(T))&&(cek==true)){
        if (T.TI[i]>=T.TI[i+1]){
            cek = true; // benar maka cek lagi
            i++;
        } else{
            cek = false; // berhenti loop
        }
    }
    return cek;
}

boolean IsMonoStatic (TabInt T)
{
    // kamus lokal
    IdxType i;
    boolean cek;
    // algoritma
    i = GetFirstIdx(T);
    cek = true; // tetap ngecek
    while ((i<GetLastIdx(T))&&(cek=true)){
        if (T.TI[i]==T.TI[i+1]){
            cek = true;// belum ditemukan & ttp lanjut pncarian
            i++;
        } else{ // != berhenti cek
            cek = false;
        }
    }
    return cek;
}

int main(){
    /* kamus lokal */
    TabInt T;

    /* algoritma */
    // read input
    BacaIsi(&T);

    if (IsMonoStatic(T)==true){
        printf("Array monotonik statik\n");
    } else {
        if (IsMonoNotSmaller(T))
            printf("Array monotonik tidak mengecil\n");
        if (IsMonoNotGreater(T))
            printf("Array monotonik tidak membesar\n");
        printf("Array tidak monotonik\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output of

```
4
4
4
3
2
Array monotonik tidak membesar
```

But the output is not working here

```
4
4
4
3
2
 // the program crash here, I need to use ctrl+c to quit this program
```

Comment: `boolean.h` - anything wrong with `stdbool.h`?

Comment: What is `GetLastIndex`?  And you have a typo in the while condition in `IsMonoStatic `.

Comment: GetLastIndex is function to get last index of array

Comment: what typo in the while condition?

Comment: We are missing part of the code, can we be sure that `BacaIsi` is not having an infinite loop ?

Comment: @QurrataAyuni You are assigning to `cek` in `IsMonoStatic`'s while loop condition, where it looks like you should be comparing with it instead.

Comment: Similarly what is the code for `GetLastIndex` which could be the faulty function? unless you run your code in a debugger and provide a stacktrace of the step you are manually exiting your program we will have very little clue of where you code loop infinitely.

Comment: ```BacaIsi``` is not having infinite loop I already test it ```BacaIsi``` and ```GetLastIndex``` already inside body off array.c, they worked fine, I think the problem is inside the main program at condition

Comment: ```IsMonoNotGreater```, ```IsMonoNotSmaller```, and ```IsMonoStatic``` these function are already tested, the problem is my if and else statement i think

Answer (score 1):

The problems are with your while loops.

```
while ((i<GetLastIdx(T))&&(cek=true)){
```

Here, I think you intended to write `cek == true`.

Looking at the control flow here, we can achieve this with a for loop. Here's an example, rewriting `IsMonoStatic`:

```
boolean IsMonoStatic (TabInt T)
{
    for(IdxType i = GetFirstIdx(T); i < GetLastIdx(T); i++)
    {
        if(T.TI[i] != T.TI[i + 1])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: thank you it works! but I think when ```cek=false``` then i dont need to increment because i will return the value of ```cek```?